# Why can't I mention my projects as answers?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, disputed-review-audits, spam

So, I saw people asking questions on SO and decided to help. Instead of just talking about the solutions, I created the solutions as open source projects and provide to them as answers. People used and liked my projects. Then, I tried to apply the same answer to similar questions. I want to saved people's time. But they are now all marked as deleted and spam.

FxCop installation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22762822

Making Entity framework implement an interface: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295995

I made attempts to explain the context, reached out to moderators (@lizardbill). Nothing seems to help.

Thanks

P.S. I provided straight answers to the questions. I don't know why they are still being declined by moderators. If you think they are not good answers, let people vote them down. Please don't delete them if they are not down voted. At All.

Comment: I suggest reading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86717/defining-the-limits-of-self-promotion and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers

Comment: Thank you. I find out about how I can have free promotion for my open source: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/free-vote-based-advertising-for-open-source-projects/

Comment: I don't mention my stuff on Codeplex even though it totally *nails* the question because I got spanked for it once.  The moderation surface is so uneven that appeals that work on Monday do not work on Tuesday with an altogether different playing field on Wednesday.  So my advice is to accept it as part of WHAT IS, and get on with it.

Answer (score 19):

This is a question that gets asked often on Stack Overflow, because we do have a lot of open source project authors here and they often recommend their projects in answers. I'm one of them, and I often struggle with how best to mention my own project without crossing over the line into excessive self-promotion.

In fact, I wrote [some detailed recommendations for how to present your open source project here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/229091/135615) in response to [a similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229085/how-to-offer-personal-open-source-libraries) on the (former) Meta.SO.

I believe what troubled people with your answers is that you left 25 answers in rapid succession, 22 of which promoted your projects. Stack Overflow is an attractive spam target, and spammers keep trying to attack the site in various ways. This has caused the community to have a strong response to anything even remotely resembling spam. Thus, these were flagged by members of the community and many of the answers removed.

Looking through your answers, I've definitely seen worse. You describe what your framework is, that you wrote it, and how to use it. However, some of these answers look like you did a search for keywords and posted answers without targeting the specific question asked. Near as I can tell, these answers weren't really what the asker was looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295412/19679

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23295581/19679

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296063/19679

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23296590/19679

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23298152/19679

and seemed to be copied and pasted to search results you found without reading the actual question. Answers need to be individually written to solve the problem at hand.

I've undeleted your answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22762822/19679

because it looks like a response to the specific question there. I'm no subject matter expert though, so if you'd like to make the case for specific other answers or edit them to be more appropriate, you could flag the individual answers for us to evaluate and undelete if warranted.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort in explaining about my violations (seems to be the right word choice here). But it is all because of my approach:
1. Search for active questions.
2. Try to group them together.
3. Build a solution that would simplify people's day to day tasks.
4. Try to introduce the solution to as many questions as possible.

Now that it triggers the spam protection system, I will have to tweak it. I will edit each of the answer and explain how people could be benefit from the solution that I proposed. What should be the most effective way to flag my edits for undelete?

Comment: I updated http://stackoverflow.com/a/23295412/3481183  Please review.

Comment: Also updated http://stackoverflow.com/a/23295581  Please review

Comment: Updated http://stackoverflow.com/a/23296063/3481183  Please review

Comment: The 3 edits that I made above would provide straight answers to the questions. I don't know why they are still being declined by moderators. If you think they are not good answers, let people vote them down. Please don't delete them if they are not down voted. At All.

Comment: Brad Larson, will any further actions be taken on my answers?

Comment: Editing does not cause the answer to be undeleted.

Comment: @Believe2014: I've taken a second look at the answers you've cited above, but I don't see enough added value to warrant undeletion.  Please stop asking us to re-review these answers; we won't.

Comment: The irony here is that similar (and even less explained) answers are widely accepted; your saren't mostly because you managed to *initially* annoy people.  To an unfortunate degree, what lives/dies around here depends on if it is seen mostly be those interested in the topic, or those interested in housekeeping.

Comment: @Believe2014 - Sorry, I was busy with a few other things and wanted to take the time to review these properly. I've undeleted a couple that you've edited to specifically answer the questions they were on. One of them you'd already presented another answer for the question, so I left that one alone.

Comment: Thanks Brad. This sounds great. Love the community again.